# MySQL join on non-unique identifier

Tags: mysql, join

I have a database table that looks like this

```
apiRequest table:

+-------+-------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
| id    |    type     |                   userId             |     device     |
+-------+-------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
| 26786 | healthcheck | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | NULL           |
| 26788 | root        | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | iPhone 6S Plus |
| 26789 | healthcheck | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | NULL           |
| 26791 | root        | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | iPhone 6S Plus |
| 26792 | healthcheck | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | NULL           |
| 26794 | healthcheck | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | NULL           |
| 26795 | root        | 054D45BF-8C0D-40D9-9917-12C86C9A1C09 | iPhone 5       |
| 26796 | root        | 054D45BF-8C0D-40D9-9917-12C86C9A1C09 | iPhone 5       |
```

On all the requests that are of `type = 'root'` a value exists in the device field, this is not the case when `type = 'healthcheck'`. All entries in this table populate the field `userId`. The `userId` field does not have a unique constraint.

I am running a query to get all the healthchecks that match certain conditions, I want to also return the `device` when I get these healthchecks, and to do that I need to match the `userId` from the `healthcheck` entries to the `userId` from the `root` entries.

Below is a working sql query, though it takes a very long time to run and is therefore not usable:

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, a.userId, b.device 
FROM apiRequest a 
INNER JOIN apiRequest b ON b.userId = a.userId 
WHERE a.type = 'healthcheck' 
AND b.id = ( SELECT max(id) FROM apiRequest c WHERE c.userId = a.userId AND c.type='root' );
```

It returns the desired result:

```
| 26749 | healthcheck | 054D45BF-8C0D-40D9-9917-12C86C9A1C09 | iPhone 5       |
| 26750 | healthcheck | 054D45BF-8C0D-40D9-9917-12C86C9A1C09 | iPhone 5       |
| 26752 | healthcheck | 054D45BF-8C0D-40D9-9917-12C86C9A1C09 | iPhone 5       |
| 26755 | healthcheck | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | iPhone 6S Plus |
| 26758 | healthcheck | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | iPhone 6S Plus |
| 26762 | healthcheck | 7B0BEA35-7D09-4D46-99C0-45EFF7D3F6E8 | iPhone 6S Plus |
```

I have tried running a `LEFT JOIN on userId` but because there are many matches in the right table ( of type `root` ) for each entry in the left table ( of type `healthcheck` ) that is not returning the result I need.

MY GOAL:

Is to find the best performing query to select all the entries of type `healthcheck` and include the matching `device` from the entries that are of type `root`.

Comment: What if the device of record 26788 was different from 26791 (the same user changed phones or has multiple phones)? With your query you would match the all health checks for a given user with the same device. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Great question @trincot. That would never happen in my situation. Therefore, it does not matter if you get the min(id) or the max(id) when you are running the query I displayed in the example that works, but performs poorly. The userId of "X" will always have the same value for device.

Comment: This question appears to be about optimization. I highly suggest utilizing the `explain plan` feature as documented in the [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html). My guess is you could speed this up by adding an appropriate index. If you update your answer with the results of `explain plan` I would be happy to help you optimize it.

Comment: @John Foley, take a look at my answer, I've attached an sql query.

Comment: @John Foley , why do you have `max(id)`? You want the **latest** `root` device, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get better performance with this query, because the sub-select has to be evaluated only once:

```
SELECT      a.id, a.type, a.userId, b.device 
FROM        apiRequest a 
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT   userId, MAX(device) device 
            FROM     apiRequest
            WHERE    type = 'root'
            GROUP BY userId) b ON b.userId = a.userId 
WHERE       a.type = 'healthcheck'
```

But make sure to have a non-unique index defined on *(type, userId, device)*. This could be done with this statement:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_apirequest_user_device ON apiRequest (type, userId, device);
```

Comment: Phenomenal. Performs very well. Thank you.

Comment: You may add a `where type = 'root'` to your inner query.

Comment: True, that might give a slight improvement ***if*** an index exists on *(type, userId, device)*. Such an index will also be useful for the outer query. So I've updated my answer with that. Thanks @IvanGritsenko!

Comment: Why did you call `MAX(device) device`? I didn't see anything about it in OP's query nor could I understand its necessity from the discussion.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko, I did `MAX(device)` based on the comments on the question where I asked about different devices for the same user, and OP said *"The userId of "X" will always have the same value for device."*. So I could have proposed `MIN(device)` as well, it is just a matter of getting the device in a `GROUP BY`query. I know that MySql would allow to go without `MAX`, but I prefer ISO SQL where possible. And that syntax requires to aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following idea:

1. Do a query using `Group By` on field `userId` at the same time applying aggregated function `max(id)`. So now we have a `max(id)` for each `userId`.
2. Join your initial table with the result of query #1 on `id`.

### SQL Code

```
select a.id, a.type, a.userId, b.device
from apiRequest a
inner join apiRequest b on a.userId = b.userId
inner join  (select max(id) id, userId
             from apiRequest
             where type = 'root'
             group by userId) as c
on b.id = c.id
where a.type = 'healthcheck'
```

It is uequivalent to your example but will run faster because of no sub-select request.

Consider also creating indexes on the fields which a participating in `join` operations.

Comment: Thanks for your additional work, Ivan. Though your provided example only returns approximately half of the results. With the current data I am testing with there are 6778 `healthcheck` records. Your query only returns 3477 records. Also, it takes 0.05 seconds to run, where as trincots query takes 0.03 seconds to run. I believe it's because we need to gather information from the apiRequest table 3 times in your query as opposed to twice in trincots query.

Comment: @John Foley, well that might be because of some `healthcheck`s does not have a corresponding `type` by `userId`. You can try to change first `inner join` to `left join` - will give you all `healthcheck`s but with NULL's.

Comment: I don't think @trincot's query gives exactly the same result as mine. However I'm **sure** my query gives the same result as yours.